# Is there a way to force `<body>` Element to respect offset? (I.e. Users current scroll position) when 'custombox' modal is fired?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working with [custombox.js](https://dixso.github.io/custombox/) along with BS4 and I'm having a little bit of difficulty with the scroll bars within the browser.

Ok so let me explain;

I have effectively a BS4 Modal (Except it's a Custombox one. They are quite similar.) With BS4 there is a class that is applied to the body tag when a modal is opened this class is as follows;

```
/* BS4 Class */
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Effectively this class hides the browsers scroll feature while the
>   modal is open.

Sadly, this isn't what I want as it causes some unsightly jittering, when opening or closing the modal.

As such, I wrote this to combat the issue;

```
/* Custom Box Lock */
.custombox-lock {
  position: fixed;
  left: inherit;
  overflow-y:scroll !important;
}
```

Effectively this class keeps the scroll bar visible, while locking the user in place. (I.e Disables Scrolling.)

**The Problem**

Unfortunately, when this class is applied by the modal firing, it jumps the user to the very top of the page. Very undesirable indeed...

As such I attempted to use, `inherit: left;` in the hopes I could force the body element to respect the scroll position but alas, I had no such luck.

> **Question:** Does anyone know of a way I could achieve my desired result, without
>   over complicating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you think `.modal-open { overflow: hidden; }` is causing the problem, then why don't you just override it to `.modal-open { overflow: scroll !important; }`? Bootstrap classes can be overritten like that.

BUT... I don't think your problem comes from that line. This just hides the overflow inside the modal itself. What you wanna do is displaying the page's scrollbar at all times. You can do that by adding

`body{overflow: scroll !important}`

to your code. This makes it so the scrollbar is always present and there is no screen adjustment happening if you open a modal.

Comment: It's not technically a bootstrap element, and has it's own set of classes. The class I tweaked was effectively Identical. As for your answer of `overflow: scroll !important;` That's effectively what I have written in my question all be it a little bit more specific. I'm specifically seeking a means of locking the viewport from scrolling and keeping the scroll bars visible. `overflow: scroll !important;` keeps the bars visible but still permits scrolling...

Comment: Hey, the thing is you applied the `overflow-y:scroll !important;` to the `.custombox-lock` class, I would suggest you add it to the `body` tag.

Comment: The class is added to the body tag though? :/